# How to forbid run on specific CPU-cores for all threads of any application, unless the thread specified by me?

Tags: c++, winapi, posix

How to forbid run on specific CPU-cores for all threads of any application, unless the thread specified by me (in Win/nix)?

To bind the threads or processes to specific CPUs cores, we can use the OS-API-functions: sched_setaffinity() in POSIX and SetProcessAffinityMask(), SetThreadAffinityMask() in WINAPI.

But if we want, that on these nuclei will not be started any other threads of many third-party applications, which currently running on the operating system, how to do it?

**UPDATE**: Need a real-time system - necessary to have specified by me threads never happened context switching, or the temporary suspension.

Possible Solutions:

- Use real-time OS, such as QNX
- In addition to binding to the processor cores, set the priority of real-time
- Use XEN-virtualization to the distribution of processor cores across Operating Systems

A page fault is easily solved using a pinned memory: (POSIX) mlock() or (WINAPI) VirtualLock()

Comment: Just don't try.  Go on, I'll bite - what XY problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no mechanisms for this in Windows or Linux - a CPU that isn't doing something will be fair game for scheduling other threads on. If you want to isolate a particular workload, it may be a better idea to use a virtual machine setup, and use its abilities to partition CPU & memory usage across the VM's.

Comment: @Martin James  Need a real-time system - necessary to have specified by me threads never happened context switching, or the temporary suspension.

Comment: @Mats Petersson  But host OS can use all cores, and I can't get a real-time system.

Comment: I don't think a general purpose OS can do what realtime operating systems are designed to do.

Comment: @Alex: That depends on what host OS you are using, and how it configures things. I'm most familiar with Xen, and it allows you to define a specific set of CPU's for one OS, and a specific set for another OS, and Dom0 (the host OS) is treated the same as any other domain (OS), so you can select "only processor(core) 1 for host, rest are used for other loads".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your process and threads to real-time priority, and they'll shove everything else out the way. Use [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the process priority and [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the threads, like this:

```
SetPriorityClass(HProcess, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
SetThreadPriority(HThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
```

Comment: Thanks! I need simply set affinity mask to bind thread to CPU core and set priority to real time - and it will solve my problem?

Comment: Give it a try and let us know how you get on. It's still allowed to context switch your threads etc, but it's unlikely windows will choose to do so with those settings to real-time (because programs rarely use them). If another program did come in with the same settings you would end up sharing the CPU with them.

Comment: Drivers... page faults... the OP is dreaming.

Comment: @Martin James  A page fault is easily solved using a pinned memory: (POSIX) mlock() or (WINAPI) VirtualLock()
What do you mean, drivers can interrupt execution threads bound with CPU-cores and with realtime priority?

Comment: This is the correct solution. As Raymond Chen points out, "what if another program did the same?" is the relevant question. With this answer, the result would be "they share the core between them, if they pick the same core. Else they get their own core". That is the correct result.

Comment: @Alex: interrupts are sent to a core, and a driver must handle them. Interrupts, as the name suggests, interrupt application processing.

Comment: @MSalters  Interrupting what? Interrupting a network interface? All of these interruptions can be launched on any randomly selected CPU-core? Or only on the core with number zero, which prioritized for OS?

Comment: @Alex: No, _interrupts_ in the context of OS/drivers are messages sent by external hardware to the CPU, which are then picked up immediately even if the CPU was running an application. E.g. if a network packet arrives, the network card will interrupt the CPU. On most systems today, these interrupts are distributed across cores. Imagine a heavy webserver - it couldn't process all interrupts with just core 0.  This distribution is typically done in hardware since it's so performance-critical.

Comment: @MSalters  And can I manage through API-OS (POSIX / WINAPI) that distribution IRQ between the CPU-cores? Assume, disable interrupts from external hardware on some CPU-cores or to allow only for the specific hardware.

Comment: No. use a real-time OS for that. BTW POSIX does not deal with driver-level problems.

Comment: @MSalters  Said here: "Hardware interrupts are serviced by a **single core** on Linux...", interrupts aren't distributed across cores  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408363/is-it-possible-to-use-the-hardware-de-multiplexing-for-highload-network-servers?noredirect=1#comment27040280_18408363

Comment: @Alex: Well, that's wrong. [Longer story](http://www.alexonlinux.com/smp-affinity-and-proper-interrupt-handling-in-linux). Check `/proc/irq/<N>/smp_affinity` on your system to see how your Linux/x86 distributes interrupts. It's not new at all, 2.6.24 or so.