# In what CPUs and OS can we distribute hardware interrupts across CPU-cores?

Tags: windows, unix, x86, arm, aix

In what CPUs and OS(operations systems) can we distribute hardware interrupts across CPU-cores for sequential arising it on different cores, for example interrupts from the network adapters?

As there have said, we can't do it in Linux(x86_64):
[Is it possible to use the hardware de-multiplexing for highload network servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408363/is-it-possible-to-use-the-hardware-de-multiplexing-for-highload-network-servers#comment27040280_18408363)

But an example we can do it in Cortex-A5 MPCore:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0434b/CCHDBEBE.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the irqbalance linux utility :

https://github.com/Irqbalance/irqbalance

I recently ported to ARM Cortex A9 based platform.

The hardware interrupts gets routed to different cores.

Comment: Thanks. Does `irqbalance` have some advantages over using an `/proc/irq/<N>/smp_affinity`? And how had solved the problem of long time synchronizing caches(through cache coherence), as described by the following link, where different parts of the same package come to the L1/L2 cache of different cores?http://stackoverflow.com/a/18528364/1558037

Comment: Ok to answer in some detail : irqbalance has three types of balancing by core, package and cache. The utility ultimately writes to 
/proc/irq/<N>/smp_affinity but based on the balancing you have set. The utility should work fine for x86 based systems but needs some tuning to be done for ARM.

Comment: Ok. I do not quite understand how it can balance by cache, because `/proc/irq/<N>/smp_affinity` can distribute only the core. It's very interesting utility. Is there somewhere a more detailed description in the form of a wiki or manual?

Comment: @Alex : Unfortunately there is not much of detail about that utility .. I also have not digged too detail into code I just blindly cross compiled it for ARM ..Yes you are right writing to smp_affinity only is per core but the core number to which the irq should be affine that decision is done based on cache ...

Comment: Thanks. And what profit perfomance in percent(approximately) did you get by using `irqbalance`, or have you results of any benchmarks?

Comment: @Alex : Unfortunately I could not see much improvement in performance but then as I mentioned the utility is tailor-made for x86 , the locations such as for finding cache levels are all hard coded for x86 , so I only chose balancing for core's . I think if I can port the code for ARM with cache and package I think there should be some improvement in the performance. You are planning to use on ARM or x86 ??

Comment: If it gives profit more than `smp_affinity`, then may be I will use on x86, and over one year on ARM(Tegra5(Logan)).