# How many maximum different CPU-Cores can be used to processing of one IP-packet?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

For example, we have 1 CPU with 8 Cores.
How many maximum different CPU-Cores can be used to processing of one IP-packet when it going over Eth0->TCP/IP->App (exclude processing in Application)?

For example, could it be 3 CPU-Cores:

1. Process hardware interrupt
2. Process checksum calculation
3. Process copy kernel-space -> user-space (whose pointer has been sent to the socket)

This is very important for the performance, as each transfer of data between the cores is very expensive.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I'm not sure about your justification for why it matters, but it is interesting from a kernel design perspective.

Comment: Seems to me that a simpler and more fruitful approach to parallelism would be by having different cores working on different packets. And 2 & 3 can be offloaded from and CPU. And if you can process multiple packets per interrupt you can amortize the cost of 1.

Comment: Most hardware already supports 2. 3 depends on system design, but is hardly to avoid. It is also done by different parts of the stack. Do completely ignore processing of packets is done at different levels, thus in different modules. At least raw Ethernet frames are normally not moved to/from user-space. In general, the kernal should maintain locality, but that is not juist a matter of Ethernet frames.

Comment: @John Hascall  Yes, I can use NAPI for the irq-coalescing in 1-step. But hardware-demultiplexing (when different cores working on different packets) requires to use large frames (JIMBO) and small IP-packets when 1 ethernet frame includes whole 1 IP-packet, or use 1 Eth per CPU-Core: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18408363/1558037  And this question is exactly about: how much expensive these steps, and the data transfer between Cores in these steps to use Ethernet-adapter with hardware TCP offload engine (offload some steps ).

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "data transfer between cores". Apart from some management data there is not much to transfer between cores, unless you mean a NUMA system architecture. While really interesting, this question is too broad for SO - too many variables. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @Alex I haven't written a TCP/IP implementation since the days of VAXstations, but it is my recollection that an IP packet (was made to) always fit in an ethernet frame.  So I'm not following your train of thought there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking you'll handle the interrupt on one core, have a chance that the actual kernel work involved in processing it will happen on a different core, and finally hand it off to an application running on a third core.  On some OSs you can set process affinity as well as interrupt handler affinity to avoid bouncing your data around.